# How to load date dynamically in angular design

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have got the similar design based on my requirement in codepen i have attached the link below:
https://codepen.io/cm002606/pen/NWWWvPm

I can able to get the design i have many thing to load the dynamic date inside the design but i can't include can anyone please help me out

app.component.html

```
<div class="appointment-container">
  <div class="appointment-title">
    <h2 class="title">Appointments</h2>
    <button
      style="outline: none"
      class="btn btn-primary float-right"
      (click)="openDialogWithTemplateRef(myDialog)"
    >
      <img src='{{path+"/assets/Add.png"}}'>
      NEW APPOINTMENT
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
   
    </div>

   
  </div>
  <div class="appointment-titlearea">
    <div class="month-display">
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        mwlCalendarPreviousView
        [view]="view"
        [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
        (viewDateChange)="closeOpenMonthViewDay()"
      >
        <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
        mwlCalendarToday
        [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
      >
        <h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate: monthview + "ViewTitle":"en" }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        mwlCalendarNextView
        [view]="view"
        [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
        (viewDateChange)="closeOpenMonthViewDay()"
      >
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="display-month">
      <h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate: view + "ViewTitle":"en" }}</h3>
    </div> -->
  </div>
  <br />
  <!--BBC/Sport/football/Scores&Fixtures-->
  <div class="container-fluid timeline-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1 d-none d-sm-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 prev-btn">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10">
        <div>
          <div class="row timeline-list">
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">1</span>
                <p class="d-block">WED</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">2</span>
                <p class="d-block">THU</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">3</span>
                <p class="d-block">FRI</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">4</span>
                <p class="d-block">SAT</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">5</span>
                <p class="d-block">SUN</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">6</span>
                <p class="d-block">MON</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">7</span>
                <p class="d-block">TUE</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">8</span>
                <p class="d-block">WED</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">9</span>
                <p class="d-block">THU</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">10</span>
                <p class="d-block">FRI</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">11</span>
                <p class="d-block">SAT</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">12</span>
                <p class="d-block">SUN</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">13</span>
                <p class="d-block">MON</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">14</span>
                <p class="d-block">TUE</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">15</span>
                <p class="d-block">WED</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">16</span>
                <p class="d-block">THU</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">17</span>
                <p class="d-block">FRI</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">18</span>
                <p class="d-block">SAT</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">19</span>
                <p class="d-block">SUN</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">20</span>
                <p class="d-block">MON</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">21</span>
                <p class="d-block">TUE</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">22</span>
                <p class="d-block">WED</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item active">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">23</span>
                <p class="d-block">THU</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">24</span>
                <p class="d-block">FRI</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">25</span>
                <p class="d-block">SAT</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">26</span>
                <p class="d-block">SUN</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">27</span>
                <p class="d-block">MON</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">28</span>
                <p class="d-block">TUE</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">29</span>
                <p class="d-block">WED</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 timeline-item">
              <a href="#" class="timeline-date">
                <span class="d-block">30</span>
                <p class="d-block">THU</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 d-none d-sm-block">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 next-btn">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div [ngSwitch]="view">
    <mwl-calendar-month-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
      (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
      (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-month-view>
    <mwl-calendar-week-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-week-view>
    <mwl-calendar-day-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Day"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-day-view>
  </div>

  <!-- Everything you see below is just for the demo, you don't need to include it in your app -->

  <br /><br /><br />

 
  <ng-template #myDialog class="container">
    <div class="newappointment-title">
      <h2 matDialogTitle>New Appointment</h2>
      <img
        src="../../../assets/close.png"
        matDialogClose
        class="appointment-close"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="hr"></div>

    <mat-dialog-content>
      <form #appointment="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onsubmit(appointment.value)">
        <img src='{{path+"/assets/edit.png"}}' />
        <input
          class="inputtext"
          ngModel
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Title"
          name="title"
          required
        />
        <img src='{{path+"/assets/attendees.png"}}' matDialogClose />
          <mat-select class="inputtext">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let response of responsedata" [value]="response">
              {{response}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
      
        <mat-radio-group
          aria-label="Select an option"
          class="appointmenttype-select"
          ngModel
          name="mode"
        >
          <h2 class="mode-appointment">Mode of Appointment</h2>
          <div class="radio">
            <mat-radio-button value="1" color="primary"
              >Online</mat-radio-button
            >
            <mat-radio-button value="2" color="primary"
              >Offline</mat-radio-button
            >
          </div>
        </mat-radio-group>
        <img src='{{path+"/assets/location.png"}}'/>
        <input
          class="inputtext"
          ngModel
          type="text"
          placeholder="Location"
          name="location"
          required
        />
        <img src='{{path+"/assets/alarm.png"}}' class="clock-icon" />
        <input
          matInput
          ngModel
          type="date"
          placeholder="Not Set"
          class="datetext"
          name="apt_date"
          required
        />
        <input
          matInput
          ngModel
          type="time"
          placeholder="Not Set"
          class="timetext"
          name="starttime"
          required
        />
        <!-- <span>
          To
        </span> -->
        <input
          matInput
          ngModel
          type="time"
          placeholder="Not Set"
          class="timetext"
          name="endtime"
          required
        />
        <img src='{{path+"/assets/description.png"}}'/>
        <input
          class="inputtext"
          type="text"
          ngModel
          mat-raised-button
          placeholder="Add Description"
          name="description"
          required
        />

        <div class="appointment-buttons">
          <button mat-button matDialogClose class="cancel-button">
            CANCEL
          </button>
          <button
            mat-button
            matDialogClose
            mat-raised-button
            class="save-button"
            type="submit"
          >
            SAVE
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-dialog-content>
  </ng-template>
</div>
<script>
  // BBC/Sport/football/Scores&Fixtures
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Timeline date picker slider scroller
    var move = "255px";
    var activeLeftPosition =
      $("div.active").val() !== undefined
        ? (activeLeftPosition = $("div.active").position().left)
        : (activeLeftPosition = 0);
    var activeWidth = $("div.active").width();
    var listWidth = $(".timeline-list").width();
    var center = activeLeftPosition + activeWidth / 2 - listWidth / 2;

    // on page load, center active div
    $(".timeline-list").animate({ scrollLeft: "+=" + center }, "slow");

    $("div.active").next("div.timeline-item").css("border-left-width", "0");

    $(".prev-btn").click(function () {
      $(".timeline-list").animate({ scrollLeft: "-=" + move });
    });

    $(".next-btn").click(function () {
      $(".timeline-list").animate({ scrollLeft: "+=" + move });
    });
  });
</script>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  startOfDay,
  endOfDay,
  subDays,
  addDays,
  endOfMonth,
  isSameDay,
  isSameMonth,
  addHours,
} from 'date-fns';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogConfig,
  MatDialogRef,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
//import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {
  CalendarEvent,
  CalendarEventAction,
  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent,
  CalendarView,
  MOMENT,
} from 'angular-calendar';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, Observer } from "rxjs";
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { PatientDataService } from '../patient-management/patient-data.service';
import { AuthServiceService } from 'src/app/auth-service.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AppointmentService } from './appointment.service';

const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3',
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF',
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'mwl-demo-component',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styles: [
    `
      h3 {
        margin: 0 0 10px;
      }

      pre {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        padding: 15px;
      }
    `,
  ],
  templateUrl: './appointment.component.html'
})
export class AppointmentComponent {


  onsubmit(data:any){
    this.service.appointmentdata(data).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log('data is pushed',data)
    })
  }
  userIdentity: any = "";
  responsedata=[]
  path = environment.imagepath;

  @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true }) modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;
  //dialog: any;
  openDialogWithTemplateRef(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {

    console.log('openDialogWithTemplateRef(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>)');
    this.dialog.open(templateRef);
    let data = '{"ot_id": "1349614973711122e40e9e99e90c2020"}';
  }

  view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Week;
  monthview: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;

  CalendarView = CalendarView;

  viewDate: Date = new Date();

  modalData: {
    action: string;
    event: CalendarEvent;
  };


  refresh = new Subject<void>();


  activeDayIsOpen: boolean = true;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,private service: AppointmentService,private http:HttpClient) {}

  dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
    console.log(
      'dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void'
    );
    if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
      if (
        (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
        events.length === 0
      ) {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
      } else {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
      }
      this.viewDate = date;
    }
  }

  

  handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
    console.log('handleevenet()');
    this.modalData = { event, action };
    // this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
  }

  setView(view: CalendarView) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  closeOpenMonthViewDay() {
    this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: 1) The code should be in the question, not just linked. 2) The description of your goal and the problem make very little sense. Can you please edit the question to fix these problems.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue i have added the code can you check